# JavaScript Visibility Blinking Out

Tags: javascript, css, visibility

I am programming an image viewer box which overlays a thumbnail gallery page. The image viewer is set to become visible when the user clicks on a thumbnail.

Currently, when a thumb is clicked, the viewer pops into visibility and then immediately becomes invisible again. I would like to know how to invoke the viewer to full visibility and then keep it there.

I am using an external .js file.

**The onclick event:**

```
<div class="thumb_box">
    <a href="" alt="gallery thumb" onclick="invokeViewer()">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../thumbs/jacob/jacob1.png"  />
    </a>
</div>
```

**The JavaScript function:**

```
function invokeViewer(){

    var viewerBack = document.getElementById('imagebox_foreground');
    var viewerFore = document.getElementById('imagebox_background');
    var currentImage = document.getElementById('current_image');

    viewerBack.style.visibility='visible';
    viewerFore.style.visibility='visible';
    currentImage.style.visibility='visible';

    return false;
}
```

**The Viewer Div's HTML:**

```
<div id="imagebox_foreground" style="visibility:hidden">
    <img id="current_image" style="visibility:hidden" src="imageurl.jpg" />
</div>

<div id="imagebox_background" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
```

**The Viewer Div's CSS**

```
#imagebox_foreground{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%; top:50%; 
    height:570px; width:880px; 
    margin-left:-430px; margin-top:-285px; 
    background-color:transparent; 
    z-index:992;
}   
#imagebox_background{
    position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; 
    height:570px; width:880px; 
    margin-left:-430px; margin-top:-285px; 
    background-color:black; 
    border-right:solid 4px rgb(40,40,40); border-left:solid 4px rgb(40,40,40); 
    opacity:.85; filter:alpha(opacity=85); 
    z-index:991;
}           
#current_image{
    display:block; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: I think that returning `false` on `invokeViewer()` may be causing you trouble. What happens if you return `true` or simply return nothing at all?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your href is being triggered and your page is being reloaded.  Add `return false` to your event handler to prevent the link from being triggered.  `invokeViewer()` is already returning false, so you can just say `return invokeViewer()`:

```
<a href="" alt="gallery thumb" onclick="return invokeViewer()">
```

Or:

```
<a href="" alt="gallery thumb" onclick="invokeViewer(); return false;">
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I suspected it was the reload, but did not know why the return false within the function was not preventing it.